# Gmail API Pub/Sub Push not stopping

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

I am developing with the Gmail API, and everything is working, I can authorize a user account to Push emails to my endpoint and send the next History ID.
The issue is with removing the account. I have deleted the account from the Google Cloud Platform, I have removed the app from Account/Settings/Connected Apps and Sites from within Gmail, however something is STILL pushing updates to my web server. I can see the request coming in and not being authorized, but it never the less is still pushing. How do I stop it in Gmail???

I receive this on my server:

```
2016/09/26 10:34:30 [D] [server.go:2202] | 503 |  41.984725ms|   match|  POST    /push   r:/push
d:  {user@name.com 2776948}
current user:  user@name.com
last history id:  2776700
doing error:  Get https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/history?alt=json&startHistoryId=2776700: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized
Response: {
  "error" : "deleted_client",
  "error_description" : "The OAuth client was deleted."
}
```

So the client is revoked, but the push still occurs. Verry weird...

Answer (score 1):

You also have to send a request to [stop watching](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/stop) the user's mailbox:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/stop?access_token={access_token}
```

Comment: Hmm I was doing this, it turned out, that if you are not responding with a success (200, 204 etc) Google continues to try as far as I can see, indefinately to get a success from your server. So even after a `stop()` it was continuing to push.... Fixed now...